# Chisel : Is there any way to slice a vector based on its value?

Tags: scala, chisel

Is there any way to slice a vector based on a delimiter?

I know that there's a function in Scala called `slice()`, which takes in the initial and final index of the sub-vector or sub-array to be sliced. Is there any similar approach to this to slice a vector when a certain value is encountered, where in the 2 parameters are the starting index and the delimiter respectively? I want it to be something like `vec.slice(start, delimiter)`.

Comment: Something like `vec.slice(start, vec.indexOf(delimiter, start))`?

Comment: Yeah, something like that

Comment: Is this slicing static or dynamic? Are the index and delimiter known at elaboration time or is this something that needs to be done dynamically in the hardware?

Comment: For my project, the delimiter is known only during execution. So it should be done dynamically